# Format for a url that goes to Google image search?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, google-api

I have a web page which has links  at the bottom like this:

```
- <a href='http://www.google.com/q?rome+photos'>photos of rome</a>
- <a href='http://www.google.com/q?paris+photos'>photos of paris</a>
- <a href='http://www.google.com/q?london+photos'>photos of london</a>
```

The idea is that if somebody clicks we go to Google search image page and we search for those images of those cities.

The questions are:

1. what's the right URL for starting an image search in Google
2. is there a place in Google documentation where I can find this ? (I searched and could not find it)
3. does Google restrict this type of usage for some reasons?

Comment: if instead of redirecting users off your page and to the image search page you can use their api to include searches into your page https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: @PatrickEvans my understanding is that custom-search will not allow me to search over the internet

Comment: you can custom search API to search all of google.. use   cx=003297764410947261360:hlyqxsuk4js   which I got from here:   https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/12499034?hl=en        for the second page just add  &num=10&start=11

Comment: This question is about exactly what I wanted to know, 9 years later. But it seems that none of the solutions below, which I have used in the past, no longer work in 2023. For example, these two URLs appear to take me to the same “regular”/“non-image” search results: http://www.google.com/images?q=Chicago and https://www.google.com/search?q=Chicago

Answer (score 131, accepted):

1. url: `https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=findSomeImage`,
2. Nothing official that I'm aware of, but [this blog has some documentation](http://stenevang.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/google-search-url-request-parameters/).
3. Nope, no limit you should worry about if you're manually clicking the urls. (I'm sure google has some kind of flood protection against bots, though)

So, the only change you have to make, is to add the `tbm=isch` option to your urls.

Comment: `tbm=isch` ("isch" = "image search")

Comment: (Bing works though ;)

Answer (score 25):

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=<SEARCH TERM>&tbm=isch
```

The `tbm=isch` is the internal google search parameter that determines what kind of search to perform.  There doesn't seem to be any official documentation on it, but this page has a decent write up:

[Google Search Request Params](http://stenevang.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/google-search-url-request-parameters/)

It looks like if you don't include the "/search" part of the string, it fills the google searchbox, but doesn't actually execute the search.

Comment: I agree - this doesn't work in Safari but it does in Chrome.

Comment: Pasting the link into chrome works. Clicking it works in both chrome and safari. But pasting it into safari does not work.

Comment: If your wanting to do something on an industrial scale, you might want to consider creating a google cloud app and then using their API to get JSON search results. A URL like this works, the cx bit says "use google" .. https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=your-google-api-key-here&cx=003297764410947261360:hlyqxsuk4js&tbm=isch&q=old+people+in+home

Answer (score 19):

Use the "images" keyword instead of "search" (this should also work for "videos", "maps", etc.)

```
http://www.google.com/images?q=your+search+terms
```

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/websearch/No-YWMdgFp8/l_SNghlwCV0J

**Update**

Following Chris F Carroll's comment below, I had a look with Fiddler. The `/images` request results in a 301 (moved permanently) response with the redirect URL in the format `www.google.com/search?q=search+terms&tbm=isch` as described by other answers here.

Contrary to what I said above (taken from the linked article), the `/video` request doesn't work. `/maps` does work, and doesn't result in a redirect.

Comment: In what way? It works for me in Chrome. I pasted "http://www.google.com/images?q=pluto+flyby" into the address bar and it showed me relevant image results. (Hmm, I typed that in with the "http" prefix but it's not showing up in the comment.)

Comment: Interesting. For me, it's hit and miss. Example: If I click your link that works, but I think my browser (safari) is making it work. If I try to copy/paste it without the trailing quote mark it gives me text, not image, results

Comment: @chris - it's not Safari making it work, it's a redirect. See updated answer. (Sorry about the trailing quote included in the link - I can't seem to edit the comment to correct it.)

Answer (score 12):

Please use below URL for google image search

```
http://images.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&safe=active&nfpr=1&q=your_search_query
```

Replace your_search_query with your own search term. Please note this url will behave differently according to the user agent. Google can identify whether this request comes from a browser or a bot

Also note you can add another query string to navigate through this image search

http://images.google.com/images?um=1&hl=en&safe=active&nfpr=1&q=your_search_query&start=30

This will make the search start from 3rd page. I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: This has added benefit of loading the non javascript image search page.

Comment: Many thanks for this! Let me just add that only 2 parameters seem necessary for an image search. You can try `http://images.google.com/images?q=your_search_query&tbm=isch`, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

This is the link that works for me: https://www.google.com/search?q=rome+photos&source=lnms&tbm=isch

Comment: `&source=` is not needed.

Comment: Even if you're providing a link with a solution, it's good to at least explain a little what's that about, what's based on, etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=<SEARCH TERM>&udm=2
```

An example with the query "malaco vingummi":

https://www.google.com/search?q=malaco+vingummi&udm=2